# Remove space after form in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Please view the following URL in IE8 and then in any other browser.

http://minorityrecruitonline.com/college/default.aspx

It looks fine in every browser except for IE8. The culprit is the extra space being included after the `</form>` tag.

Does anyone know how to remove this space from IE8? I have tried all the usual tricks of adding margin:0 and padding:0 and even display:inline to the form tag, and nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
<style>
form{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
</style>
```

it might work

Comment: i`m on a mac at the moment so i can`t test it.. sorry

Comment: eventhough this did not answer the question above, it helped me tremendously.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a pretty straight-forward design, but the table layout and inline styles and scripts make it impossible to read and / or trouble-shoot. I´d say that a complete re-write in css is what is required.